# String to list without #\ in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'd like to turn String into lists. For example, http => (h t t p).

I try:

```
(defun string-to-list (s)
  (assert (stringp s) (s) "~s :questa non e una stringa")
  (coerce s 'list))
```

but if I do

```
(string-to-list "http")
```

results:

```
(#\h #\t #\t #\p).
```

Can I remove #\ ? 
 thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Why would you do that? What you ask is to split a string (a one-dimensional array of characters) into a list of symbols. Do you really want that?

`#\h` is a character object printed.

You can print them differently:

```
CL-USER 8 > (princ #\h)
h

CL-USER 9 > (prin1 #\h)
#\h
```

Let's print the list using `PRINC`:

```
CL-USER 10 > (map nil #'princ (coerce "Hello!" 'list))
Hello!
```

Btw., since strings, vectors and lists are sequences, you can MAP directly over the string...

```
CL-USER 11 > (map nil #'princ "Hello!")
Hello!
```

Answer (score 3):

You can turn a string into a symbol with `intern`. You can turn a character into a string with `string`. Interning a lower-case string might cause it to be printed as `|h|` instead of `h`, so you'll want to `string-upcase` it. Putting all that together gives:

```
(loop for c in (coerce "http" 'list)
      collecting (intern (string-upcase (string c))))
```

Comment: thanks ! so there is no way to result (h t t p ) instead of (H T T P) ?

Comment: @r1si: I'm demonstrating a way to do that in an additional answer. I would have used the comment, but they're bad for multi-line code examples.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding upon larsmans' answer, you can print lowercase symbols unquoted if you change the readtable:

```
(let ((*readtable* (copy-readtable)))
  (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :preserve)
  (prin1 (loop for c in (coerce "http" 'list)
               collecting (intern (string c)))))
```

This will print `(h t t p)` and return `(|h| |t| |t| |p|)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can print characters unescaped. See the variable `*PRINT-ESCAPE*`.

The function `WRITE` has a keyword parameter `:ESCAPE` for that:

```
(defun string-to-list (s)
  (assert (stringp s) (s) "~s :questa non e una stringa")
  (write (coerce s 'list) :escape nil)


CL-USER 11 > (string-to-list "abcd")
(a b c d)
(#\a #\b #\c #\d)
```

In above example the first form is printed by calling `WRITE` and the second form is the return value printed by the REPL.

Comment: Just printing the whole list with `princ` will also print its elements unescaped.